# como faco para comparar uma session?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

gostaria de saber como faco para comparar uma `session` de uma pagina `php` com o `ajax` pelo simples motivo exibir uma `alert` mais bonito ao cliente a comparacao que eu tenho e o seguinte ele compara não parte em `php` se existe usuário logado se não existe ele da a mensagem de `alert` tem como eu fazer isso com o `ajax` ? para simplesmente mudar o `alert`?

este e o código `php` que faz a verificação esta no topo da pagina que e chamada quando eu clico em comprar:

```
if ( ! isset( $_SESSION ) || ! isset( $_SESSION['clienteSession'] ) || $_SESSION['clienteSession'] != true )
{
  echo "<script type=\"text/javascript\">
       alert(\"Você Precisa estar Logado para Efetuar a Compra!\");
       window.location='login.php';
    </script>";  
}
```

Resultado:

```
 if (!isset( $_SESSION ) || !isset( $_SESSION['clienteSession'] ) || $_SESSION['clienteSession'] != true ){
        echo "nao logado";

      }
```

parte js:

```
$("#comprar").click(function(){
        $.ajax("carrinho.php",{

        }).done(function(r){
            if(r == "nao logado"){
                alertify.error("Você Precisa estar Logado para ter Acesso a Esta Página");
                setTimeout("window.location=login.php",2000);
                return;
            }
        }).fail(function(){
            alertify.error("Opss Algo deu Errado");
        })
      });
```

Comment: ? eu sei que ele da certo quero saber como que faco por requisicao ajax isso para voce leu minha pergunta? la esta escrito que eu quero saber como faco para quando clicar no botao comprar ele enviar o ajax para essa pagina que contem esse trecho de codigo e o AJAX fazer a verificacao se esta logado

Comment: Alert nunca é "bonito". Se você está usando PHP, mostre a mensagem na tela de maneira não intrusiva. A experiência do usuário fica melhor, e seu trabalho fica com uma cara mais profissional. Aliás, quase sempre que alguém chama JS de dentro do PHP, é sinal de problema no uso das ferramentas.

Comment: sei la cara nao curto muito o alert padrao fica `este site diz` nao e legal isso. mas tem como fazer o que eu quero @Bacco ?

Comment: em vez do alert, você pode mostrar os dados numa DIV na página, e com CSS deixar ela muito bem apresentável.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Primeiro crie a chamada do AJAX jQuery:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "verificar.php"
    , success: function(result){            
        if(result == "NAO LOGADO"){
            // Colocar mensagem bonitinha aqui...
            // Faz a logica para ir pro login
        }           
    }
});
```

Depois no arquivo `verificar.php` comparamos a SESSION

```
session_start();
if ( !isset( $_SESSION['clienteSession'] ) || $_SESSION['clienteSession'] != true )
{
  echo "NAO LOGADO";
  exit;
}
```

Comment: eu tinha pensado em fazer isso mas eu achei que nao ia dar certo e acabei nem tentando vlw

Comment: Com essa logica vc vai ter que pensar um pouco na hora de redirecionar para o login, talvez dar um `setTimeout` para que o usuário veja a mensagem, mais a principio é isso

Comment: nao ta de boa agora era so isso msm

Comment: Dei um +1 na sua, pois é um complemento bom pra idéia. A parte dos ISSET dá pra enxugar um pouco, pois tem que dar um SESSION START antes, entao acredito que o 1o isset nao seja necessário.

Comment: Valeu, faz sentido não ter o primeiro isset mesmo... vou editar...

Comment: nao esta adiantando muito nao ele esta deixando passar@JhonatanSimões

Comment: vou editar minha perg do modo que eu fiz

Comment: da uma olhada la @JhonatanSimões eu editei a pergunta com a resposta que eu fiz

Comment: Poxa, deve ter ficado show agora mano... usabilidade é tudo

Comment: nao funciona nao para no meu if ele passa nao retorna o alert como eu queria

Comment: Veja agora.... coloquei o `exit` para parar dentro do if

Comment: antes sem o exit ele me retornava a pagina inteira com o echo no topo da pagina agr com o exit nao mudou nd a unica coisa e que ele nao mostra mais a pagina inteira ele mostra uma pagina escrita nao logado

Comment: bom eu resolvi como eu tinha que passar um get eu precisei declarar do tipo get e tambem precisava tirar meu href do html senao nao iria

Answer (score 2):

Segue uma sugestão de refatoração:

```
session_start();
if ( isset( $_SESSION['clienteId'] ) && $_SESSION['clienteId'] > 0 ) {
  echo '<div class="verdinho">você está logado</div>';
  // no lugar do echo, retorne no ajax a mensagem
} else {
  echo '<div class="vermelhao">você precisa se logar</div>';
  // no lugar do echo, retorne no ajax a mensagem
}
```

Sem ver o resto do seu código, fica complicado dar detalhes. O importante é que você pegue o retorno desse código e mostre numa DIV ou lugar apropriado da página, sem obrigar o usuário a clicar OK, etc.

Nada impede de você na mensagem de erro colocar já o link para o formulário de login, ou retornar mais de uma variável, uma com a mensagem e outra com um status, indicando logado ou não. É só um ponto de partida.

O importante seria fazer o AJAX que chama tomar uma providencia com a informação, e não a página chamada.

Note também que em vez de testar se é cliente logado ou não, estamos testando se o ID do cliente é maior que zero. Assim, no futuro, você pode personalizar as mensagens de acordo com o "level" de autorização do cliente, dependendo da parte do site que chamar.